# no SSL certificate detected on vercel after deployment

Tags: ssl-certificate, hosting, vercel

I've published my project on vercel and connected it to a domain. after that it should work fine, but when redirected to the domain link it doesn't work, and in my domain service it displays `no SSl detected`. so how can i register my domain with the ssl?

Comment: Please reach out to Vercel support. They should be able to assist you with this issue due to https://www.vercel-status.com/incidents/ktnq1hq3x23x